# Meaning of summation from + to - index

Tags: notation, index-notation

I am currently working through [this document](https://iers-conventions.obspm.fr/content/chapter6/icc6.pdf) describing the calculation of an accurate Geopotential model.

In equation 6.15, there is a double summation. The first summation specifies summation for all values of f (frequencies of waves in this case), and the second indicates that, for every frequency, we should perform a summation of the following expression for + and -. The expression includes multiple sets of +- signs, with one of them being actually a -+ sign.

My question is, does this summation for + and - mean to perform a summation of 2 terms, the first one obtained by taking the first sign in each +- sign (i.e., for the case of the -+ sign, it would be a -), and the second one obtained by taking the second sign in each +- sign (i.e., a + for the -+ sign)?

Editing to leave the specific formula (I am including a simplified to show only the notation I'm having trouble with):

$$\sum_{+}^- (\mathcal{C}^\pm \mp i\mathcal{S}^\pm)e^{\pm i\theta}$$

Comment: It is better to use MathJax and place the sum in your post than to make us look for it.

Comment: Please add the specific equation you are talking about as [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your question

Comment: If you write the formula here, we could make a guess as to what is meant, although it might depend on context. As is there is not enough information to say anything useful.

Comment: Apologies all, I have now edited with a simplified version of the equation in MathJax showing the problematic notation

Comment: This is from equation 6.15, on page 11. The expression looks more natural if you include the second summation sign. Your guess seems to be the right one.

Comment: Probably means $\,\sum_{+}^- (\mathcal{C}^\pm \mp i\mathcal{S}^\pm)e^{\pm i\theta} = (\mathcal{C}^+ - i\mathcal{S}^+)e^{+ i\theta} + (\mathcal{C}^- + i\mathcal{S}^-)e^{- i\theta}\,$ indeed. The $\,\mp\,$ usually indicates that the signs must correspond throughout, so not all plus/minus combinations are summed.